# Multidimensional String Addressed Datastructure in Visual Basic.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-structures

I'm looking to create a set of sums that are addressed / used like this in Visual Basic.Net:

```
String ContractTimeFrame, Region, BillingGroup = "IndexHere"
Double Value = 42 
SumCollectionOrWhatever(ContractTimeFrame)(Region)(BillingGroup)(Customer) += Value
```

Is there a way to do this easily?

Note that 'SumCollectionOrWhatever' is a bunch of Doubles that start at zero then increase towards accounting totals.  My apologies if the question is poorly stated; I couldn't put the object definition into it because I don't know what it should be.

My final datastructure would look something like this:

```
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Annual"]["West"]["Heavy"]["ABC"] == 123
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Annual"]["West"]["Light"]["ABC"] == 456
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Annual"]["East"]["Heavy"]["ABC"] == 123
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Annual"]["East"]["Light"]["ABC"] == 456
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Annual"]["Total"]["All"]["ABC"] == 1158
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Weekly"]["East"]["Heavy"]["ABC"] == 789
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Weekly"]["West"]["Light"]["ABC"] == 12
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Weekly"]["East"]["Heavy"]["ABC"] == 456
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Weekly"]["West"]["Light"]["ABC"] == 12
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Weekly"]["Total"]["All"]["ABC"] == 1269
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Grand"]["Total"]["All"]["ABC"] == 2427
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Annual"]["West"]["Heavy"]["DEF"] == 123
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Annual"]["West"]["Light"]["DEF"] == 456
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Annual"]["East"]["Heavy"]["DEF"] == 123
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Annual"]["East"]["Light"]["DEF"] == 456
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Annual"]["Total"]["All"]["DEF"] == 1158
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Weekly"]["East"]["Heavy"]["DEF"] == 789
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Weekly"]["West"]["Light"]["DEF"] == 12
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Weekly"]["East"]["Heavy"]["DEF"] == 456
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Weekly"]["West"]["Light"]["DEF"] == 12
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Weekly"]["Total"]["All"]["DEF"] == 1269
SumCollectionOrWhatever["Grand"]["Total"]["All"]["DEF"] == 2427
```

NOTE: Edited to add another level of organization.  Yes, there are four layers, and I'm beginning to think a four-dimensional array hidden in an object with intelligent addressing / addition is my best bet.  The addressing is generally binary (East and West, Weekly and Annual, Heavy and Light) so the datastructure won't be HUGE, but I don't know if .Net has a built-in b-tree or something that would work properly for this.  Generic Collection?  Anyone?

Comment: What should be your result? Do you want the string "IndexHere42" or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I eventually want to iterate through this collection (or whatever) and output all the summations.  SumCollectionOrWhatever gets modified over the course of a couple loops and increases in size.

Comment: Note: spent some time increasing the overall readability of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do use a Dictionary

```
Dim SumCollectionOrWhatever As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Integer))))()
```

However you *won't* be able to do this:

```
SumCollectionOrWhatever("Annual")("West")("Heavy")("ABC") = 123
```

until something is added there. It will be a bit complex to add a new entry

**Edit**: added extension method to operate on this data structure

Put this in a module:

```
<Extension>
Public Sub Add(ByVal d As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Integer)))), p1 As String, p2 As String, p3 As String, p4 As String, value As Integer)
    Try
        d(p1)(p2)(p3)(p4) = value
    Catch
        Try
            d(p1)(p2).Add(p3, New Dictionary(Of String, Integer))
            d(p1)(p2)(p3).Add(p4, value)
        Catch
            Try
                d(p1).Add(p2, New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Integer))())
                d(p1)(p2).Add(p3, New Dictionary(Of String, Integer))
                d(p1)(p2)(p3).Add(p4, value)
            Catch
                Try
                    d.Add(p1, New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Integer)))())
                    d(p1).Add(p2, New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Integer))())
                    d(p1)(p2).Add(p3, New Dictionary(Of String, Integer))
                    d(p1)(p2)(p3).Add(p4, value)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    ' throw it back?
                End Try
            End Try
        End Try
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew I could probably use that type of solution, but it seems that I'd need a string of If...Then...Else trees to check on existence of locations for values then add them.

Comment: Yeah, that's fantastic and slick and possibly exactly what I need.  I'll probably accept that as an answer as soon as I implement it.  Unfortunately, I won't be able to today.  Thank you for your help, and look forward to a rep bump Monday or Tuesday when I can spend the time testing / implementing it.

Comment: Okay, there were minor modifications required for my particular implementation, but I highly appreciate the help and have accepted the answer.